# don't open Team Explorer by default

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, team-explorer

In my VS2010 I always have an extra tab "Team Explorer" when I launch VS2010. But I don't use TFS, so this tab is totally useless and annoying, so I close it each time. How do I make it closed by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open visual studio, go to tools, options, Source control and in the current source control plug in change the option to None. This should stop TFS the behaviour you described in the question.